# Interactive ActionScript interpreter?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there some sort of interactive ActionScript interpreter? Similar to Firebug's JavaScript command line or Python's interactive shell?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try [AS3Eval Library](http://eval.hurlant.com/) - it is AS3 compiler implemented in AS3. It has [simple interactive shell](http://eval.hurlant.com/demo/).

Comment: Ah, very cool – that's pretty close to what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Accidentally I've found another one: Wonderfl - build flash online - http://wonderfl.kayac.com/

Answer (score 5):

There's also Frontal:

http://code.google.com/p/frontal/

It has an ActionScript interpreter built into it. It's based on the ECMA 2.62 (JavaScript) standard so it's not full AS3 and doesn't support things like packages and classes but it's still extremely handy.

As I mentioned, the interpreter is part of a larger library implementing the Frontal language but if you were so inclined you could pretty easily just rip out the interpreter.

Or you could just use it in Frontal. And if you did then you do get a console that allows you to run ActionScript in a primitive shell. For example, go to the Frontal website. (I can't post the link because my reputation is low but it's frontalcode + com.) Right-click and choose "View Frontal Source..." This will open the Frontal console. At the bottom of the console, click "command line." This is your "shell."

Try something like this say:

5 + 4 * 10

or

movie.alpha = 0.5

Answer (score 1):

Actionscript is a compiled language and the compiled byte code is executed by the Flash Player Virtual Machine. There are a number of tools out there that will create Actionscript byte code based on Actionscript source code. I'm not aware of the existance of any tools that will intrepet AS byte code and execute it other than Adobe Flash Player.

Although I do not say it's not possible, I haven't seen nor heard of any tools that gives you an interactive shell for Actionscript.

Comment: Oops ! This is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**[flash-console](https://code.google.com/p/flash-console/)** project does exactly that. They have a [demo](http://console.junkbyte.com/sample.html) and an online [help](https://code.google.com/p/flash-console/wiki/CommandLineHelp).

- Special commands start by a slash like `/help`
- Variables can be stored and accessed via `$some_name`
- `/` changes current scope to the last returned value.

The project is meant to be integrated in your project.